# What means "initial point" & "current point" in SVG and what is the difference

Tags: python, svg

Let me say at first that this may seem very stupid question, but SVG frequently tends to be underestimated (e.g. see a description of Z/ClosePath command @ [Mozilla dev site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d) and compare it to [SVG Rec. 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand)).

According to [SVG Rec. 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataMovetoCommands):

> The "moveto" commands (*M* or *m*) establish a new *current point*. The
>   effect is as if the "pen" were lifted and moved to a new location.

I.e. "current point" is `M` or `m`.

[Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataClosePathCommand) it is written that:

> The "closepath" (Z or z) ends the current subpath and causes an automatic straight line to be drawn from the *current point* to the *initial point* of the *current subpath*.

So, am I right if I assume that "initial point" is the point at which current subpath have been started? But if the work being performed is done on current subpath, and "current point" == `M` or `m`, then "initial point" also should be the equal to `M` or `m`. How is this possible, and what I'm not getting here?

---

Thanks to Robert Longson here's an explanation what "current point" and "initial point" are. The error in my logic were caused by unspotted word "establish" in the statement "The "moveto" commands (*M* or *m*) **establish** a new *current point*. The effect is as if the "pen" were lifted and moved to a new location." I.e. `M` or `m` populated this "variable" only at the beginning of processing.

E.g., imagine path data like this:

```
m1 c11 c12 c13 z1 m2 c21 c22 c23 z2
```

In it, `m1` will populate `current_point` variable and will also set new `initial_point`. After that, when processing will go to the next drawing command, `current_point` will become last point of that command. E.g. (`V` is the pointer to the current processing state):

```
V
m1 c11 c12 c13 z1 m2 c21 c22 c23 z2
initial_point = current_point = m1
    V
m1 c11 c12 c13 z1 m2 c21 c22 c23 z2
current_point = c11.last_point
        V
m1 c11 c12 c13 z1 m2 c21 c22 c23 z2
current_point = c12.last_point
...
                  V
m1 c11 c12 c13 z1 m2 c21 c22 c23 z2
initial_point = current_point = m2
```

Comment: Yes, it does. You basically need `Z`, if you want to close a path. You can reach the same behavior, if you repeat the first point in the end.

Comment: That's true provided the path does not have markers on it.

Comment: @"You can reach the same behavior, if you repeat the first point in the end." Well, it's not completely true: "When a subpath ends in a "**closepath**," it **differs** in behavior from what happens when "**manually**" closing a subpath via a "lineto" command in how ‘stroke-linejoin’ and ‘stroke-linecap’ are implemented."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what it means. The initial point is that of the first (mandatory) move.

Comment: Thanks. After reading more thoroughly I've spotted that I missed key word "establish" in "The "moveto" commands (M or m) *establish* a new current point." Completely forgot that "current point" is the last point of the previous subpath.